# How to set painter of printer correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qpainter, qprinter, qtextdocument

I'm printing a set of tables, each table should get its own page and could be long. The basics are working, but I don't get the footer painted. The problem is the footer will be painted in an extra document(s).

According to the docs I must set the painter to the device. The device is painter, that's correct, but how do I set the painter to the correct Block? Or is it wrong to act this way?

The goal is to use this document twice. 1st attempt is to print, the second a `QTextDocument` where I can pic up the `QTextTable`'s and to compile it with another document elements.

**Working example**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *

content = [['section 1', [1,2,3,4]],['section2', [5,6,7,8]]]

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

document = QTextDocument ()
printer = QPrinter()
painter = QPainter(printer)
pageRect = printer.pageRect ()

tableFormat = QTextTableFormat ()
cellBlockFormat = QTextBlockFormat ()
cellCharFormat = QTextCharFormat ()
cellCharFormat.setFont (QFont ("Arial", 10))

for rownr, line in enumerate(content):
    cursor = QTextCursor (document)
    mainFrame = cursor.currentFrame ()
    # header
    cursor.setPosition (mainFrame.firstPosition ())
    cursor.insertHtml ("This is the table for  %s"%line[0])

    # table
    table = cursor.insertTable (3, 4, tableFormat)
    for colnr, col in enumerate(line[1]):
        print("col:", col)
        cellCursor = table.cellAt (rownr + 1, colnr).firstCursorPosition ()
        cellCursor.setBlockFormat (cellBlockFormat)
        cellCursor.insertText (str (col))

    #footer
    painter.begin(printer)
    painter.drawText (0, pageRect.bottom(), "I may be the footer")
    painter.end()
    # section finished
    cursor.setPosition (mainFrame.lastPosition ())
    tableFormat.setPageBreakPolicy (QTextFormat.PageBreak_AlwaysAfter)
    cursor.insertBlock (cellBlockFormat, cellCharFormat)
document.print_(printer)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the last paragraph? I mean the part "where I can pic up the QTextTable's and to compile it with another document elements.". Consider that is not a very good idea to change the document structure *while* printing.

Comment: My understanding from the doc's of `QTextDocument is a container for structured rich text documents` is that I can access the `document element`'s by `A QTextDocument can be edited programmatically using a QTextCursor, and its contents can be examined by traversing the document structure.` as describes in [rich text structure](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-structure.html). So, my idea is to build elements like frontpage, preamble, table of content, lists, report sheets and store them in  `QTextBlock, QTextFrame, QTextTable, and QTextList` classes which can be inserted with `insertBlock()`

Comment: Do I understand this wrong?
Basicly I'm strugling with mixing painted elements and textblocks.

Comment: You have to understand that "painting" is always an absolute and *final* result of a relative structured format. If you want to add element while printing, you cannot rely on the automatic `print` method, because it already paints the whole document, so you need to implement painting manually, by extending what `drawContents` does.

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying, that means I have to create and collect the blocks (textblocks, frames, tables, ...), in a list e.g. calculate its text-length, divide it by the pageRect length and then I may paint the footers and afterwards the pages as shown in some other questions. Sounds complex. Especially for the list of content, if its result is more than than 1 page.
To be honest I can't belive that, because it's more or less a standard behavior and should be supported in an easier matter. In my opinion.

Comment: No. Just read the documentation about [`drawContents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#drawContents) and possibly study its source code (along with `print`), then use it *and* add the custom content after each page is completed. Note that `print` does not use it, so you have to call it manually for each page, and you will have to work out a *lot* of things related to DPI, scale and unit management (print is not as immediate as it seems, even for PDF).

Comment: The documentation is a little bit scrimpy if it comes to howtoaboutit. I'm not familar with C++ and python not that long. But now I know in which direction I have to work. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premise: this is more a hack than a solution, as it's a **dirty** workaround.

The idea is to subclass QPrinter, override the `newPage` method and draw the footer accordingly. This requires that the `printer` instance is manually updated with footers.

Unfortunately, there's another important catch: I've not been able to print the footer as long as there's only one page.

In the next days I'll try to look into it again, and find if there's a solution for it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *


class FooterPrinter(QPrinter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.footers = {}

    def paintEngine(self, *args):
        engine = super().paintEngine(*args)
        self.currentPage = 0
        return engine

    def drawFooter(self):
        text = self.footers.get(self.currentPage)
        if not text:
            return
        painter = super().paintEngine().painter()
        dpiy = painter.device().logicalDpiY()
        margin = dpiy * (2/2.54)
        rect = QRectF(margin, margin, self.width() - margin * 2, self.height() - margin * 2)
        fm = QFontMetrics(painter.font(), painter.device())
        size = fm.size(0, text)
        painter.drawText(rect.left(), rect.bottom() - size.height(), 
            size.width(), size.height(), Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop, text)

    def newPage(self):
        self.drawFooter()
        newPage = super().newPage()
        if newPage:
            self.currentPage += 1
            self.drawFooter()
        return newPage

content = [['section 1', [1,2,3,4]],['section2', [5,6,7,8]]]

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

document = QTextDocument()
printer = FooterPrinter()
printer.setOutputFileName('/tmp/test.pdf')
pageRect = printer.pageRect ()

tableFormat = QTextTableFormat ()
cellBlockFormat = QTextBlockFormat ()
cellCharFormat = QTextCharFormat ()
cellCharFormat.setFont (QFont ("Arial", 10))

for rownr, line in enumerate(content):
    cursor = QTextCursor (document)
    mainFrame = cursor.currentFrame ()
    # header
    cursor.setPosition (mainFrame.firstPosition ())
    cursor.insertHtml ("This is the table for  %s"%line[0])

    # table
    table = cursor.insertTable (3, 4, tableFormat)
    for colnr, col in enumerate(line[1]):
        cellCursor = table.cellAt (rownr + 1, colnr).firstCursorPosition ()
        cellCursor.setBlockFormat (cellBlockFormat)
        cellCursor.insertText (str (col))
    cursor.setPosition (mainFrame.lastPosition ())
    tableFormat.setPageBreakPolicy (QTextFormat.PageBreak_AlwaysAfter)
    cursor.insertBlock (cellBlockFormat, cellCharFormat)

    printer.footers[rownr] = 'Note for page {}: some text.\nNew line\nAnother new line'.format(rownr + 1)

document.print_(printer)
```

Comment: Great idea to sublcass `Qprinter`. Regarding the single page, maybe another hack with including an empty page and delete it afterwards will help. I can't work on it next days, will continue asap. But I don't think that this is a dirty hack, more a genius solution.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't remove pages afterwards (if not by using external tools), because as soon as `print_` returns the file is already written and closed (which also means that you cannot call `newPage()` afterwards). Also, almost everything `print_` does is private, I was "lucky" just because I realized that `paintEngine` and `newPage` are explicitly called.

Comment: My workaround is to decide using the above class if more than 1 page and use the first solution for only 1 page. Not perfect, but it works.